# Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin or updati

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to add Firebase to my app like tutorial.
I'm getting this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.4.0.

**My gradles.**

**build.gradle (Project):**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io"}
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (app):**

```
dependencies {

    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/NativeXMonetizationSDK_v5.4.12.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/SuperRewards-3.1b.jar')
    compile files('libs/TrialpayAndroidSdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/adcolony.jar')
    compile 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'

    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile files('libs/adscendmedia1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile 'com.github.leonardoxh:custom-font:1.2'


    compile 'com.github.leonardoxh:custom-font:1.2'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.2.6'


    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mediationsdk-6.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/personasdk1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar')
    compile files('libs/vungle-publisher-adaptive-id-3.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/chartboost.jar')
    compile files('libs/applovin-sdk-6.1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/heyzap.jar')
    compile files('libs/revmob.jar')
    compile project(':appGradeLib')
    //compile project(':sensiblefacebooksdk')
    compile project(':googleplayserviceslib')
    compile files('libs/AdxmiCustomizedSdk_v1.2.0_2015-11-13.jar')
    compile files('libs/AdxmiSdk_v5.4.0_2015-11-12.jar')
    compile project(':unity-ads')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.febaisi:custom-textview:0.0.3'
    compile 'com.scopely:fontain:1.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: As @HristoStoyanov mention in his answer you are using old version of Firebase Libraries. If I understand it well you must always use same version of Google Play Services. You can find it here: [Set Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) and [Firebase Libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
```

make google services using the same version(all 9.4.0 or all 10.0.1)

Comment: And also, dont use deprecated version like compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+' and  classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+' . 
this will only slow down your build time and sometimes lead to error as your IDE will keep on checking new version.

Answer (score 2):

You are using old version of the Firebase libraries.
These are the latest:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```