# Error: fix the version conflict (google-services plugin)

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631113/please-fix-the-version-conflict-either-by-updating-the-version-of-the-google-ser) SO thread, I know there are version conflicts, but issue still persists after new versions from Google.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.1.

My **build.gradle(Module: app)**

```
....
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
   compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**What changes are required now?**

Comment: Make sure version all play services is same.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I think you change

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
```

Comment: So, only this was the issue! I wish I had tried it before posting :\

Comment: Make sure all Firebase SDK version is as same as play services version.

Comment: I was having the same kind of issue but all my version numbers were updated. After few minutes I discovered that it was giving error because I had put apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the bottom.

As soon as I placed it at bottom it worked. Can someone explain me why it happened?

Comment: how to do this resolution on phonegap build

Comment: How to fix this in an Ionic/Cordova build?

Comment: it's better to check maven repository versions from [this](https://mvnrepository.com) link and change versions.

Answer (score 40):

Same error gets thrown when

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

is not added to bottom of the module `build.gradle` file.

Comment: this worked for me, I just added it to the bottom of the file

Comment: Saved me! One has to wonder why Gradle smells so much like black magic though.

Comment: I wounder why setting plugin line on the top of Gradle will make an error and setting it at the bottom of file will work correct ??? Is there any one known the actual reason .

Answer (score 30):

You must use only one version for all 3 libs

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
```

OR only use only 10.0.1 for 3 libs

Comment: amazing. Spent hours trying to figure out a build issue bc firebase was trying to use 17x and play-services-location was 16x.

Thanks

Comment: Update, One can use individual versions https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593656/6891563

Answer (score 21):

Please change your project-level `build.gradle` file in which you have to change your dependencies class path of `google-services` or `build.gradle` path.

```
buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

The google play services requires all its dependencies to have the same version. But if you look at your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
```

There is one that has a different version.

It can be solved by changing the version to (in this case) `11.0.4`.

This applies to both Firebase and Google Play Services - both have to have matching versions that also correspond with each other. If a Firebase dependency is `10.0.1` and a Google Play Services dependency is `11.0.4`, the same error will occur.

Note that in some cases, there can be a library that has a different version of a library (e.g. library `x` uses `play-services-games:10.0.1` while you use `11.0.4` for the dependencies in your app)

---

## Edit

This answer does NOT cover the newer versions where versions are individual. Update `com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0` and check [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/) (or some other maven/gradle artifact search tool) to find the newest versions.

Comment: Update, latest dependencies may have individual versions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593656/6891563

Answer (score 6):

With

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0
```

You have to use:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

This fixed my problem

Answer (score 5):

For fire base to install properly all the versions of the fire base compiles must be in same version so

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4' 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4' 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
```

this is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, the firebase database was pointing to 11.8.0 .after changing all the related jars to 11.0.4 this issue is resolved at changes the SDK level.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Important Update

> Both Firebase & Play-service dependencies are having independent versions unlike past. If
>   you have version conflicts then you can update your
>   `com.google.gms:google-services`. and start defining independent version.

#### Step(1): Update `com.google.gms:google-services`

> Open project level `build.gradle` and update `com.google.gms:google-services` to version `4.1.0` [MUST CHECK newer if available](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gms/google-services?repo=bt-android-tools).

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' //< update this 
    }
}
```

#### Step(2): Update Firebase dependencies **[Latest Versions](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)**

Firebase dependency versions can be individual.

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3    //Analytics, check latest too
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2    //Realtime Database, check latest too
```

#### Step(3): Update Play Services dependencies **[Latest Versions](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)**

Play services versions also can have individual versions.

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2 //Ads, check latest too
com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6   //Analytics, check latest too
```

**Still having issue?**
You can check which dependency is making conflict by reading **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50158079/6891563)**.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** google services and Firebase library to **latest version**

google services

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.1'
```

firebase

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

as the message says go to:
[com.google.gms.google-services versions](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)

And copy the last version's number . Mine was less than 3.3.1.
Then in project's build.gradle put/change  dependencies node as :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2' // as it was before             
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1' // <-- the version change                  
        }
```

Then I synced the project and error went

Answer (score 0):

All google services should be of same version, try ***matching*** every ***versions***.

**Correct one is :**

```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
```

**Incorrect Config is :**

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
After All Working for 6 hours i got the solution...

Simple Just what ever the plugins you defined in the build.gradle file... for ex: google services plugins or firebase plugins or any third party plugins all the **version code** should be same..

Example: In my application i am using following plugins...

    // google services plugins
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.6.0'

    //firebase plugin
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'

    //Third Party plugin
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
```

In the above plugins version code(ex:10.0.1, 16.0.0, 11.6.1) are different I was facing **fix the version conflict (google-services plugin)** issue

```
Below for all plugins i have given single version code(11.6.0) and the issue is resovled...

 // google services plugins
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.6.0'

    //firebase plugin
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.6.0'

    //Third Party plugin
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'


**Syn Gradle**...

Go to Build>>Rebuild Projcet...

Sure it will work....@Ambilpura
```

Answer (score -2):

install or update google play services. Secondly, check your 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' version . Check , this  by upgrading it if still not work to 3.1.0