# Conflict in build.gradle at com.google.android.gms

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I try to run my app I got this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.

But I've already upgrade the gms to latest version where I do mistake? Could you explain me that?

Here my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev186-1.23.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-java6', version: '1.23.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-jetty', version: '1.23.0'
    compile 'com.github.PierfrancescoSoffritti:AndroidYouTubePlayer:4.1.7'
    //compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha2"
    //compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha2"
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.16.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.22.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-android', version: '1.22.0'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: I'll remove in case

Comment: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` put this line at the end..hopefully it will solve your issue !!

Comment: dont remove , if its the duplicate , it will be flagged.. but first try the solution !!

Comment: I've already done what do you suggest, but he doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: fix the version conflict (google-services plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500934/error-fix-the-version-conflict-google-services-plugin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4' XX
```

the above two versions are **`DIFFERENT`**

**Use** ,

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
```

instead

and also add

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services
```

at the **bottom** *instead* of **top** !!