# Error : Please fix the version conflict?

Tags: java, android

While using the dependencies shows error on either **google-services plugin** or on **com.google.android.gms**.How to resolve this???

build.gradle(Module app)

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'

implementation 'com.twotoasters.jazzylistview:library:1.2.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
//here its shows an error
```

Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the **google-services** plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of **com.google.android.gms** to 12.0.1.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle(Project XYZ)

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
   // classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' // google-services plugin
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

 allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
  }

   task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: fix the version conflict (google-services plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500934/error-fix-the-version-conflict-google-services-plugin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use same version of dependencies

Use this

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
```

Instead of this

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
```

Answer (score 2):

The dependencies should be of same version. Otherwise it will give conflict error.

Replace this

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
```

To

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
```