# Android conflict dependencies

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm learning `React-Native` and created an app to show map using `react-native-maps` library.

I have followed all steps in [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md) but I got this error :

[image]

my dependencies is :

```
dependencies {    
  implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
  }
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
  compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
  compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
  compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
  compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
  compile project(':react-native-fcm')
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'    
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your Firebase version and google-play-service version should be same. You can visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500934/error-fix-the-version-conflict-google-services-plugin for more.

Comment: By the way, if you want to use the both firebase as well google-play-service, use version `15.0.0`

Comment: hey @meditat thank you so much.. it's worked..

Comment: Welcome,Happy to help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **SAME** version.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
```

You should check [**`Google APIs`**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) & [**`Firebase APIs`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) list.