# Fixation Of Version Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, build.gradle

I am working on Android App with the Firebase database but after linking database with firebase I found problem regarding to Version Conflict.
I am using version 3.1.3.
I have searched a lot and I found different solution related to that but Didn't resolve my problem.
Here are the previous questions available on Stackoverflow

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.usmanali.homeinventoryapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500934/error-fix-the-version-conflict-google-services-plugin)
   The Dependanies portion in Gradle file

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

Comment: add your gradle file and the error that you are getting

Comment: I have just added the gradle file

Comment: I have change It but now showing an Error on this Line
"implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"'

Comment: Error mean a red line under the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
```

into this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
```