# Android studio: "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification "

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, libraries

I'am trying to code an app. My samsung phone has android version 8.0. I thought my app was crashing cause I was running it at 8.1 (API 27). So i downgraded the SDK versions etc.. But now when I try to build an APK, it gives me this error:

***All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:design:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).***

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.socialapps.socialme"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

***'implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'*** is underlined with red lines. Can someone help me please? Thanks:D

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45500934/6296561

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Answer (score 0):

The Keyword `compile` is deprecated. Replace them with `implementation` word.. And update versions of libraries.. to do this you can set cursor on any library and press Alt + Enter and select update to .... for example change  these libraries to these verions:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```