# “All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification” in android studio

Tags: android, build.gradle

I use the current version of mapbox SDK navigation. Navigation SDK for Android Current version: v0.32.0 and I got a error if I add the implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.30.0' in the build.gradle (Module:app)

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 27.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0

Gradle:

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //Mapbox Dependencies
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.2.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.11.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.32.0'}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: fix the version conflict (google-services plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500934/error-fix-the-version-conflict-google-services-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of issues are debugged by executing `./gradlew app:dependencies` (app is a module name, yours can be different) and reviewing dependency tree for dependencies that bring different compat versions with them.

In your case, apparently the dependency already known (`com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui`) thus you can try to resolve it like this:

```
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.32.0') {
    exclude module: 'exifinterface'
}
```