# when I put "play-services-ads", implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' makes error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, admob

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espressocore:3.0.2'
}
```

These were my codes.

---

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
```

But when I add this AdMob code,

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

this code makes error:

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can
```

---

What can I do?

[image: capture image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: fix the version conflict (google-services plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500934/error-fix-the-version-conflict-google-services-plugin)

Comment: Use `./gradlew app:dependencies`, then you can find two different versions.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'`
 is implicitly using `support libraries 26.1.0`. You can **override** the libraries by adding the exact version of the conflicted libraries. Add something like this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:customtabs:27.1.1'
```