# How to resolve the issue to mixing dependency versions?

Tags: android, version, mixing

I'm getting an error regarding mixing of dependency versions . Few days back it was working absolutely fine but from nowhere the issue popped up .

It's showing : All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0-alpha1, 28.0.0. Examples include com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0-alpha1 and com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0

I'm using Firebase dependencies also , is it causing any trouble ?

I tried to add some extra dependencies (as popped up) , but nothing is working .

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "namantiwari.epplieschool"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.4"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
```

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: fix the version conflict (google-services plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500934/error-fix-the-version-conflict-google-services-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Android X is supposed to solve these issues.

[How to migrate to Android X](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)