# Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin'] (For input string: "+")

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, ionic4

I want to implement push notifications with Firebase Cloud Messenging service. I added :

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
npm install @ionic-native/fcm
```

In `app.component.ts` :

```
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';

// ...

constructor(private fcm: FCM)

// ...

this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
    console.log('Token :', token);
});
```

This make me an error in desktop, because Cordova is not available, it's ok.

But when I want to test on android, as usual, I make :
`ionic cordova run android --device`

And this give me an error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\<username>\Documents\weezchat_ionic\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated\billingtests-FCMPlugin.gradle' line: 21

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
   > For input string: "+"

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova run android --device exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I'm working with :

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.1.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 8 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : Windows 10
```

This is \platforms\android\cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependency-updated\billingtests-FCMPlugin.gradle content :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.+'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.+'
}
// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
```

Comment: Same issue here.  And other issues when trying other push plugins.  There does not seem to be any way to make this work without some hack to a file and even then there are other issues that follow.  I have been at this for days on this particular push issue.  And weeks with issues related to Ionic 4 and things that used to work before.

Comment: @VariousArtist So you haven’t found a solution for Ionic 4 ? I tried others push plugins too, but it didn’t work ..

Comment: No I am still having problems.  I think we need to do some hack in the project.properties file under the android platform folder, but I am not sure exactly what to change there.  Everything I have read on this seems to be slightly different but nothing has worked for me yet

Comment: This is one link I am reading about now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500934/error-fix-the-version-conflict-google-services-plugin

Comment: I am also reading this to try to figure it out https://developers.google.com/android/guides/versioning#strict_version_matching

Comment: This looked the most promising!  Alas it didn't work for me, but I think the fix is in here somewhere  https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue and was finally able to solve it using a bit of guesswork with the information in this link:
[cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release)

This involves adding a special plugin to try and set the desired play services version number.  This particular setting worked for me:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=16+
```

Basically this seems to be simply adding a version number automatically into the **config.xml**:

```
<plugin name="cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release" spec="^2.1.0">
    <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="16+" />
</plugin>
```

Perhaps your situation you need a different version number, or maybe it'll be the same since you are using Ionic 4 and trying to add the push plugin.  Either way, I believe the answer is in this setting somewhere.

*NOTE:  this is in conjunction with the plugin **cordova-plugin-firebase**

Comment: I installed it ! And it build successfully ! So thanks for it !
But, have you tired it with FCM plugin (`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated`) ?

Comment: @Emilien I seem to be making good progress with the cordova-plugin-firebase, so I haven't yet tried with the other one you mentioned yet (although it was one of many I had tried before and I do plan on giving it another go now that I can build).
Glad I could help -- Can you mark my solution as the "Correct Answer"? :-)

Comment: Alright ! I finally use @angular/firebase. Now I can get the device token. Next week I will try to send push notifications to firebase !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it was because I missed the `com.google.gms:google-services` dependency. I did it because I regenerated the Android files in Flutter:

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    }
```

Make sure you follow the instructions in the [set up documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).