# ERROR regarding Google Play Services library in build.gradle for Android

Tags: android, gradle

I am facing some issue regarding the build. I am trying to integrate the google photos api in my app. So, I added the below dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.photos.library:google-photos-library-client:1.3.0'
```

After that, I am facing build issue due to some conflict:

```
    ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[1.16.
1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.16.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-core@[1.16.1], but grpc-core version was 1.21.0
```

Here I am posting all the dependencies:

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:4.3.2'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.ncorti:slidetoact:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.1.1'
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.photos.library:google-photos-library-client:1.3.0'

    // JSON Parsing
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.vipulasri:timelineview:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.seatgeek:placesautocomplete:0.3-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:2.1.2'
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha11') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-classroom:v1-rev135-1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.robertlevonyan.view:MaterialChipView:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev305-1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.3.4'
    implementation 'us.belka:androidtoggleswitch:1.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0"

    // Optional for XMPPTCPConnection
    implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Make sure Firebase SDK / google play services are all in the same version, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500934/error-fix-the-version-conflict-google-services-plugin) will give some more accurate answers.

Comment: I don't think that is a reason. If that is the case, then I can't update to the latest version.