# FCM AND ABMOB Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: ionic-framework

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.+

Comment: I find solution
1)Remove plugin cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release
2)ionic cordova platform rm
3)ionic cordova platform add
4)plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated - plugin.xlm 61-62 line change 10.+

Comment: 5)cordova-plugin-admob-free - plugin.xlm add inside tag platform name=“android”

<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.+" />
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.+" />
plugins\cordova-admob-sdk\plugin.xml
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" default="10.+"/>
    <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.+" />
    <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.+" />
</platform>
I hope this helped you to fix this problem

Comment: 7)repeat the item 2 and 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: fix the version conflict (google-services plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500934/error-fix-the-version-conflict-google-services-plugin)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask well formatted questions. You can also answer your own question if you have found the answer, instead of posting the answer as comments.