# Version Conflict either updating the version of the google-services plugin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

So I tried to connect my firebase database to my android studio application.I get this error:

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

I changed the version but it still does not work. As you can see I changed the version 16.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I don't see the problem. I am stuck on this for hours.

Comment: maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500934/error-fix-the-version-conflict-google-services-plugin) can help or also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631113/please-fix-the-version-conflict-either-by-updating-the-version-of-the-google-ser)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure You have gms classpath provided in your `Project` build.gradle, like this:

```
dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
```

Comment: I changed it to that. Now it gives me the following error: Cause: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.ModuleComponentIdentifierImpl.getModuleIdentifier()Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleIdentifier;

Comment: @jantjesmith The same problem has been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56412795/12010542)

Comment: I still don't get it... Gradle projectsync failed. I don't understand that link you send me. Do I need to add this line : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0' ?

Comment: If You dont already have this line, then I think You are looking into the wrong file.

Comment: Do i need to change it to 3.1.0?

Comment: I fixed it already. I needed to update Android Studio to the latest version. Thanks